# Chromecast - Cast Dialogue doesn't have shadow and can't cancel from outside touch

Tags: android, casting, dialog, kotlin, chromecast

I just recently started working with the Cast SDK and while following the guide to setting it up (found here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate). I integrated the cast button onto my example app, however for some reason it does not look like how it's suppose (?) to look?

For example, my app's cast dialogue:
[My example app Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i00i.png)

vs an example app that follows the design standards (https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android):
[CastVideos-Android Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3ZX4.png)

If you notice, the CastVideos-Android one has a back-shadow associated with the dialogue and can be dismissed by pressing anywhere on the screen.

Here is all of my code since it's a very basic implementation (I wrote it in Kotlin):

MainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var castContext: CastContext? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)

    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(applicationContext, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item)

    return true
}
```

CastOptionsProvider class:

```
class CastOptionsProvider : OptionsProvider {
override fun getCastOptions(context: Context?): CastOptions {
    return CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context?.getString(R.string.app_id))
            .build()
}

override fun getAdditionalSessionProviders(context: Context?): MutableList<SessionProvider>? {
    return null
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating support library version to 27.0.2 in project gradle should fix the issue.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Support Library Version history: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-0-2

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the issue. Also didn't know that the support library had a revision history, it's very informative; thank you for also including the link.